# How to display a controller variable in a sapui5 XML view?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How can I display a controller-variable in my sapUI5 XML-view?

So far I have a **controller**:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.myApp.myController", {
        onInit: function () {
            this.myName = "Jon Doe";
        }
    });
});
```

And a **XML-view**:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.myApp.myController"
    xmlns="sap.m">
<Panel>
    <content>
        <Label text="bind controller myName to this label"/>
    </content>
</Panel>
```

Is this possible without using Model-bindings? If not: what is the smartest (shortest) way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want to avoid model binding? With model binding maybe not the shortest, but a typical short way would be:

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
"use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.myApp.myController", {
        onInit: function () {
            this.myName = "Jon Doe";
            var oViewModel = new JSONModel({myName: this.myName});
            this.getView().setModel(oViewModel,"view");
        }
    });
});
```

and the binding in the view:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.myApp.myController"
    xmlns="sap.m">
<Panel>
    <content>
        <Label text="{view>/myName}"/>
    </content>
</Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hoped that there might be another way to do it. But you are right: The model-binding is a better solution than accessing the view in the controller.

Comment: How can I use this code snippet in a controller, where I'm already initiating a Model in the `onInit` function? I already have `var oModel  = this.getModel("setting"); this.getView().setModel(oModel);` - How can I merge this with your code snippet above without overriding one model?

Comment: I am not sure, I got your question right, and I have not done much with SAP UI5 lately. But you can set multiple models in the same view, just giving them different names (second parameter of setModel). So if you set the model with this.getView().setModel(oModel2, "model2") you can access the values of the model in the view using text="{model2>/myName}".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is possible to use controller variables in the view.

But there is a shortcut to this problem: just get the desired control by its `id` from the view after the view is rendered and set any value you want to the control:

```js
return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.myApp.myController", {
    onAfterRendering: function () {
        sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("<label's id>")).setText("Jon Doe");
    }
});
```

Of course, the "Jon Doe" text from the above example could be a variable:

```js
var sText = "Jon Doe";
sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("<label's id>")).setText(sText);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I dont want to manipulate the View directly in the controller...

Comment: There is no need to call `sap.ui.core.byId()`, you have `byId()` in the `Controller` itself, so you would just use `this.byId()`. Ref: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller/methods/byId